# Como salvar parâmetros alteráveis no sistema?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, configuração, app.config

Tenho um projeto ASP.NET MVC e faço uso do `web.config` para guardar alguns parâmetros que serão usados pelo sistema, mas não deverão ser alterados por nenhum usuário.

Agora tenho que implementar alguns outros parâmetros que poderão ser alterados pelos usuários, **sem ter que reiniciar a aplicação** (como acontece quando é feita uma alteração no `web.config`). Pensei nas seguintes soluções:

1. Agrupar os parâmetros por categorias e criar uma tabela para cada uma delas, colocando um registro onde as colunas possuiriam o valor de cada parâmetro da categoria, esse registro poderia ser alterado a qualquer momento.

Mas nesse caso fiquei um pouco incomodado em ter em um banco de dados relacional (Microsoft SQL Server) tabelas independentes com um único registro em cada. Esta poderia ser considerada uma má prática por fugir do conceito de relacionamento?

2. Criar uma única tabela com duas colunas (`varchar` nas duas), uma para o nome do parâmetro (único na tabela) e outra para o valor. Essa tabela faria o papel do meu `web.config` e eu poderia buscar os parâmetros pelo nome.

Esta solução me cheira muito mal! Pois não consigo *tipar* os diferentes valores dos parâmetros e posso ter problemas em uma possível migração futura do banco, ou caso alguém acabe apagando os dados.

Pensei se poderia existir alguma solução, como NoSQL por exemplo, gerando um arquivo com dados na estrutura JSON que poderia armazenar os diferentes tipos de parâmetros, e podendo ser alterados a qualquer momento pelos usuários.

Nas aplicações ASP.NET MVC existe alguma opção para esse problema?

Comment: **1**. Não sei o que você está considerando uma má prática, mas é uma ideia ruim porque cada parâmetro vai ser uma nova tabela. Flexibilidade zero. **2**. Se você não precisa do tipo, não tem porque se preocupar com ele. Se você precisa do tipo, essa é uma solução ruim. "**3**". NoSQL é legal, mas usar um banco de dados inteiro pra salvar meia dúzia de parâmetros é um grande exagero, não acha? Principalmente se você pode simplesmente salvar estes valores num arquivo JSON qualquer. Aliás, qual o problema em criar um arquivo simples?

Comment: A propósito me parece que essa pergunta só assumiria respostas principalmente baseadas em opiniões.

Comment: Suas colocações fazem muito sentido @LINQ e de fato posso também usar um arquivo simples. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Agrupar os parâmetros por categorias e criar uma tabela para cada uma delas, colocando um registro onde as colunas possuiriam o valor de cada parâmetro da categoria, esse registro poderia ser alterado a qualquer momento.
>
> Mas nesse caso fiquei um pouco incomodado em ter em um banco de dados relacional (Microsoft SQL Server) tabelas independentes com um único registro em cada. Esta poderia ser considerada uma má prática por fugir do conceito de relacionamento?

Nem toda tabela precisa ter relacionamento.

Consegue dizer porque é má prática? Eu não consigo. Parece invenção. Parece ser só um gosto.

Eu preferiria nem separar tudo em categorias, faria elas na própria tabela. Mas depende do caso.

Já pensou em manter um histórico das alterações? Aí cada alteração seria uma linha. Não estou dizendo que precise, mas pode ser mais útil do que imagina.

> Criar uma única tabela com duas colunas (varchar nas duas), uma para o nome do parâmetro (único na tabela) e outra para o valor. Essa tabela faria o papel do meu Web.config e eu poderia buscar os parâmetros pelo nome.
>
> Esta solução me cheira muito mal! Pois não consigo tipar os diferentes valores dos parâmetros e posso ter problemas em uma possível migração futura do banco, ou caso alguém acabe apagando os dados.

Isso é tão bom que tem até uma [forma normal que indica fazer assim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_normal_form).

Se tem problemas com o tipo crie uma coluna com ele para decidir o que fazer.

Assim como pode ter uma coluna indicando que categoria pertence.

Se mantiver histórico de alterações pode ser mais interessante fazer assim.

Mas pra ser sincero eu prefiro o primeiro, esse é um caso que eu adotaria se tivesse certos requisitos que em geral não tem.

> Pensei se poderia existir alguma solução, como NoSQL por exemplo, gerando um arquivo com dados na estrutura JSON que poderia armazenar os diferentes tipos de parâmetros, e podendo ser alterados a qualquer momento pelos usuários.

Usar um outro banco de dados NoSQL só por causa disso? pra mim é uma solução terrível.

Por que precisa de JSON? Não vejo razão. Para as categorias? Na maioria dos casos esses parâmetros poderiam ser *flat*.

As versões atuais do SQL Server suportam [JSON nativamente](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server). As antigas podem usar um `VARCHAR` para armazenar o JSON, só dá ligeiramente um pouco mais de trabalho.

## Outras soluções

Pode colocar em um arquivo também, não importa o formato. Eu prefiro dentro do banco de dados, mas não vejo razão porque isto funcionaria pior que o DB a não ser que tenha alguma restrição de acesso aos arquivos de forma direta.

Em tese pode até continuar usando o `web.config` e manda lê-lo para fazer as modificações na aplicação. [É possível controlar se a aplicação reinicia ou não](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides).

Pode ser que nem todos os requisitos tenham sido informados. Aí pode ter uma razão para não usar uma das soluções citadas.

Answer (score 2):

Eu proponho a solução "4":

Use o Banco de dados que já está na aplicação, crie uma tabela com todos os parâmetros, com nome e valor, e no campo de valor, como é String, você pode usar objetos no formato JSON também, caso precise.

Se precisar saber do tipo, adicione mais um campo para isso e, na rotina que lê os parâmetros, interprete esse campo e faça o parse da string para o tipo desejado.

Nos casos de falta de parâmetro, considere assumir um valor padrão, caso não encontre na tabela o campo ou esteja com valor inválido.

> posso ter problemas em uma possível migração futura do banco, ou caso alguém acabe apagando os dados

Você também teria problemas se alguém acabar apagando os dados dos usuários, clientes, vendas... então esse não é um motivo contra essa abordagem.